# Why is so much memory taken up, and why isn't it cleared when I close the window?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-management, memory-leaks

**Background**

I have an application that shows a list of customers. The user can create a new window to view the details of a specific customer.

Part of the creation process of the new window creates a `List<OverviewItem>`, where `OverviewItem` is defined as

```
public class OverviewItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public OverviewItem(string title, string info)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Info = info;
    }
}
```

followed by 25 lines of code similar to the following:

```
overviewItems.Add(new OverviewItem("some label string", "some value string"));
```

I then bind the list to a DataGrid which is defined in the XAML of the window, as follows:

```
dgOverview.ItemsSource = overviewItems;
```

When I run the application I can see in the Task Manager** that between the point where the list is created and the point where the 25th item is added to it (before the DataGrid binding), almost 20MB of memory is taken up.

The problem is that when I close the window that memory is not cleared. If I open the window again another 20MB of memory is taken up, and it keeps taking up 20MB of memory every time every subsequent window is opened.

I was under the impression that the .net framework would manage the memory for me, but it doesn't appear to be doing that in this case. After a few days of usage the application will be taking up more than 1.4GB of memory at which point the users start experiencing `OutOfMemoryException` errors.

** I know it's not a memory profiler, but it's the only thing I have at the moment

**Question**

So the question is:

1. Why would so much memory be taken by the creation of what appears to be a few simple objects.
2. Why wouldn't it be cleared when the window is closed, how can I force it to clear?

Comment: In Windows Task Manager have you checked the Processes tab to see if those processes still exist when you close the window?

Comment: Just as @daryal pointed out, do you have any events binded to the new window?

Comment: _After a few days of usage the application will be taking up more than 1.4GB ..._ - Is this speculation or are you actually witnessing this?

Comment: Hi Henk - I've seen this. I could actually reproduce it by closing & re-opening the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no direct answer, even the UI objects may be consuming large memory, do not just count the objects.
2. I guess, you have an event bind to the newly created windows. If you do not de register to events, the objects will not be collected by GC.

For example if you have an event defined in main window and child windows are registered to it; GC will not collect child windows. Then the objects referenced by the child window will not also be collected, like the list of `OverviewItem`s. You may use WinDbg to diagnose which objects are not collected and why. Refer to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx).

Comment: sorry I took so long to accept this, it took this long to get to investigate the issue and it turns out events were the culprit. It's tricky enough to track down this issue. I finally cracked it by using the ANTS memory profiler.